# Spinner in fragment becomes slow?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I added a spinner in a fragment. It works but not as i expected. The spinner when being selected is very slow and becomes unresponsive. In the logcat without a filter, it would return the error message : **Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of spinner** and **W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.**   here is my code : `

```
public class FourthTab extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener` {

private View rootView;
private ViewGroup container;

public FourthTab() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_tab, container, false);
    this.container = container;

    makeSpinner(rootView, getContext());

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item

    //TextView tes = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tes);
    //tes.setText(item);



    Handler mhandler = new Handler();
    mhandler.postDelayed(new DisplayToast(getContext(), "Selected2: " + item), 100 );

}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


/*agar prosess calling ke network hanya dilakukan apabila fragment terlihat    */
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed())
    {
        //Only manually call onResume if fragment is already visible
        //Otherwise allow natural fragment lifecycle to call onResume
        onResume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!getUserVisibleHint())
    {
        return;
    }



}

private void makeSpinner(View rootView, Context context) {

    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.semester_spinner);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Automobile");
    categories.add("Business Services");
    categories.add("Computers");
    categories.add("Education");
    categories.add("Personal");
    categories.add("Travel");

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
```

Please, can someone suggest what is happening to it? I already tried this method : https://www.laurivan.com/attempted-to-finish-an-input-event/
 but it still didnt work and I tried to find this error on Google ***Window already focused, W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.*** ignoring focus gain of spinner here is my code but never get any good point. Thank u

```
public class DisplayToast implements Runnable {
private final Context mContext;
private final String mText;

public DisplayToast(Context mContext, String text) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mText = text;
}

public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, mText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: why are you using handler to display toast?

Comment: Post your DisplayToast class also...I think problem is there only

Comment: by some suggestion to use it @sravs . and here the DisplayToast class

Comment: your code works fine for me. there is no lag nor error

Comment: do you got error like this : 

Window already focused, W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed. ignoring focus

Comment: no I am not getting any error... though your code with handler works for me, you just try removing that handler(Toast) and logging the selected item.

Comment: i feel fool, but it happen on me..... how can i prove it :D

Comment: any suggestion what that only happen on my machine ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139456/discussion-between-sravs-and-navotera).

Answer (score 0):

as someone comment on my question i become suspicious that this about the integrated device / emulator. so i install genymotion emulator to try this. fortunately it works.

the default emulator is : Nexus 5 API 21
and the geny motion emulator is samsung S3

hope it would make other get informed